# Android BLE not finding specific device on Samsung Galaxy S8+

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having weird problems discovering a specific BLE device (DSD-Tech HM-10). Here is how I can characterize the problem:

**Setup:**

Android Devices used: Raspberry Pi 3, Samsung Galaxy S8+, Samsung Galaxy Tablet S2.

BLE: DSD-TECH HM-10, 2 other BLE devices including other DSD-TECH (H3)
Couple BLE apps, mainly BluetoothLeGatt, and gatttool on the Raspberry Pi

**Observation:**

Raspberry Pi 3 and Samsung Galaxy S2 can discover (and connect) to all the BLE chips.

Galaxy S8+ cannot discover the DSD-TECH HM-10 but can discover (and connect) to the others.

**Conclusion**

Is this an Android bug? What can cause the S8+ to not even discover the BLE device?

By the way, I have two of the same BLE device that cannot be discovered by the S8+. Both cannot be discovered.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the DSD-TECH?

Comment: You probably mean: "Discover" since I cannot even discover that specific device on S8+. I use app called BluetoothLeGatt, and app called nRF, and even the phone's Bluetooth scan. I do discover other BLE devices.